# Javascript bloqueado por display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Tengo dos menus en una página. Uno carga para disposivos de más de 992px y el otro para dispositivos menores.
El caso es que el menú de los dispositivos grandes tiene animaciones de bootstrap (es un accordion). Bien, intentaré explicarme antes de pegar el código.
Si cambias el tamaño de la ventana  desaparece el menu grande para aparecer el pequeño y viceversa (medias querys para hacer display none en el que corresponda).
Bien pues si la página se cargó en el menu pequeño, el otro menu, que de normal va perfecto, deja de funcionar al redimensionar. Agrandas la página y desaparece el menu pequeño, aparece el grande, eso bien. Pero el javascript que usa bootstrap para el accordion deja de ir (no cambia las clases de las tags etc).

En una frase, el menu que tiene animaciones bootstrap sólo funciona si la página se ha cargado con él activo, si se ha cargado con el otro menu y por tanto este está en display:none, no funciona luego (aunque aparecer si que aparece).

Por lo visto tiene algo que ver con que al cargar la página los elementos estaban en display:none. Es lo único que puedo aportar de luz. Gracias de antemano y pego el código:

```css
 @media (max-width: 992px) {
    .menuLateral {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media(min-width:992px){
    .menuMovilBoton, .menuMovil{
        display:none;
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/menu-item.png&quot;);">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="colapsador perfil collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"
         aria-expanded="false">Mi perfil
        </a>
      </h4>
      <div class="iconTainer esconderContainer">
        <img src="../../img/miPerfilMenu.png" class="esconder">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">

      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="facturacion.aspx">Facturación</a></li>
          <li><a href="direcciones.aspx">Direcciones</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/menu-item.png&quot;);">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="colapsador facturas collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"
         aria-expanded="false">Facturas</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="iconTainer esconderContainer">
        <img src="facturasMenu.png" class="esconder">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">

      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="facturas.aspx">Todas las facturas</a></li>
          <li><a href="347.aspx">Mi 347</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/menu-item-selected.png&quot;);">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="colapsador pedidos" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true">Pedidos</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="iconTainer mostrarContainer">
        <img src="pedidosMenu.png" class="mostrar">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="pedidos.aspx?ped=todos">Ver todos</a></li>
          <li><a href="pedidos.aspx?ped=curso">En curso</a></li>
          <li><a href="pedidos.aspx?ped=final">Finalizados</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/menu-item.png&quot;);">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="colapsador catalogos collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6"
         aria-expanded="false">Catálogos</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="iconTainer esconderContainer">
        <img src="catalogosMenu.png" class="esconder">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="catalogos.aspx?c=1">Ver General</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalogos.aspx?c=2">Ver segundo</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalogos.aspx?c=3">Ver tercero</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Faltaría el código de ".menuMovil" y ".menuMovilBoton" pero funcionar funciona perfectamente y al no tener bootstrap alguno no entra al caso. 
(Pd las rutas de imgs etc las he reescrito así que igual hay algo raro en alguna, pero eso no es el problema.)

Comment: si estas utilizando boostrap, no es mas sencillo utilizar el hidden-md y hidden-sm, y si no lo es, en que caso yo redimencionaria una pagina web a un menor o mayor tamaño ademas de desarrollo.

Comment: Lo mismo iba a comentar yo. Lo que @AlejoFlorez dice es lo cierto. En vez de usar un `display: none`, debes usar `hidden-md`. Saludos

Comment: O por qué no hacerlo desde el mismo Js?
Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, puedes intentar:

`$("elementoAocultar").fadeOut();`

O también, `$("elementoAocultar").hide('slow');`

Comment: desde Js he probado y acaba dando el mismo problema, si al cargar la página está oculto, luego aunque le haga un show() el Js del menu ya no va. Luego probaré la opcion de usar las clases de bootstrap y posteo el resultado.

Comment: Nada, usando bootstrap pasa exactamente lo mismo. He visto por ahí un intento con clone(). Lo que hacía es clonar el menu al cargar la página y luego cuando necesite mostrarse se borra el viejo y se añade el nuevo, pero aún así me pasa.  



    function ajustarMenu(query, menu) {
    
       if (query.matches) {  //min-width:993px
          $(".menuLateral").remove();
           $(".contenedorZona").prepend(menu);

    } else {
        $(".menuLateral").remove();

    }
}


menu se rellena en el document.ready con:
  var menu = $(".menuLateral").clone();